# PingFederate: what is PartnerSpId in case of agent-to-agent mapping

Tags: pingfederate

I'm trying to use PingFederate server to connect multiple applications into one SSO network.

Server is installed with both IDP and SP roles.

Because IDP and SP are on the same server I'd like to use agent-to-agent mapping.

I'm using agentless kit.

After DropOff, I have to redirect to URL that includes PartnerSpId.

PartnerSpId is only configured in IDP-to-SP connection and not in agent-to-agent mapping.

Does this mean that agentless kit cannot work with agent-to-agent mapping?

Answer (score 4):

PartnerSpId is only relevant when you are connecting to a partner (can be a loop-back connection, that's a different story), where you'd use the /idp/startSSO.ping endpoint ([doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/concept_idpEndpoints.html)). For adapter-to-adapter mappings, which I assume you meant with agent-to-agent, you'll use a different endpoint, /pf/adapter2adapter.ping, which has its own query parameters ([doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/concept_systemServicesEndpoints.html)). You can still append the REF query parameter, and it will function the same way.

Don't take the examples/sample applications *that* literally, they're there to show functionality, and must be adapted per use case.

Comment: Thank you mehmet-y :)
I did not realize adapter2adapter.ping was there.